# URL 'Text fragments' with 'anchor'

Tags: url, anchor, url-scheme

Browsing, for example, on [this page](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_del_complemento) from a mobile browser (Opera), all sections are closed, so you need to open its [anchor](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_del_complemento#Dettagli_molecolari_del_C3) to see that paragraph. Now, how to highlight the title, `Dettagli molecolari del C3`, of that section with [text fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Text_fragments)?

In general, is it possible to use an `anchor` together with `text fragments`?

I tried (without success):

`https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_del_complemento#:~:text=Dettagli%20molecolari%20del%20C3`

or:

`https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_del_complemento#Dettagli_molecolari_del_C3:~:text=Dettagli%20molecolari%20del%20C3`

or:

`https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_del_complemento#Dettagli_molecolari_del_C3&text=Dettagli%20molecolari%20del%20C3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `prefix-` and `-suffix` to delineate a specific instance of the text

[https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_del_complemento#Dettagli_molecolari_del_C3:~:text=via%20alternativa-,Dettagli%20molecolari%20del%20C3,-%5Bmodifica](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_del_complemento#Dettagli_molecolari_del_C3:%7E:text=via%20alternativa-,Dettagli%20molecolari%20del%20C3,-%5Bmodifica)

(You can copy & paste that but clicking it won't work here because links have to include `rel="noopener"`, which SO won't allow me to add. Oddly, the link works only when composing/editing this answer.)

Chrome and Edge now have [Copy to link highlight](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Copy+to+link+highlight) in the right-click context menu that creates a link with the text fragment.